Cascading deletion in SQLite with cleanup function needing referenced data
I have a SQLite database structure, together with foreign references, which I'd like to incorporate into my external code logic, but there's a catch...
To illustrate my question here's a simplified database structure:

When a user is deleted all related events shall also be removed. However, there's more to deleting an event than just removing it from its table: an event cleanup involves tasks outside of the database, such as notifying the invitees.
Fortunately, SQLite can do calls to external functions with parameters, which can be the cleanup callbacks that take care of these tasks.
I have defined the foreign reference in a way that will cascade the deletion processes as well as a cleanup function via a trigger, called before an event is deleted.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlite3


def cleanup_event(author):
    print(f"Cleanup event {author}")
    # Need to get access to user attributes!
    print(f"{author} attributes are ?")


conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
conn.create_function("cleanup_event", 1, cleanup_event)
conn.executescript(
    """
CREATE TABLE user(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    attributes TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE event(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    author TEXT NOT NULL,
    invitees TEXT NOT NULL,
    location TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY(author) REFERENCES user(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TRIGGER delete_event_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON event BEGIN SELECT cleanup_event(OLD.author); END;
INSERT INTO user(name, attributes) VALUES ('Alice', 'phone: 123');
INSERT INTO event(author, invitees, location) VALUES ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Somewhere');
DELETE FROM user WHERE name = 'Alice';
"""
)

Here's an online executable version.
I have not been successful in getting the user attributes from the event cleanup callback.
My assumption is: the cascading deletion process deletes the user first and then cascades to the event deletion, meaning that when the event deletion cleanup callback is called the user does not exist anymore, preventing it from accessing the user's attributes.
How can I achieve this cascading deletion and cleanup solution, where information belonging to a reference is needed, in an elegant way?
